# A mathematical model for HIV-1 under treatment is given by the system of differential equations:

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

A mathematical model for HIV-1 under treatment is given by the system of differential equations:

$$I'(t)=0.06V(t)-0.5I(t)$$
$$V'(t)=cV(t)$$
$$N'(t)=100I(t)-cN(t)$$

where, at time t, I(t) is the number of infected cells, V (t) is the concentration of viral particles, N(t) is the number of non-infected virus particles and c > 0 is a constant parameter.

Find the general solution for this system.

How would I go about doing this question, would I need to form this into a matrix and find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Comment: Yes.  It sounds like you know how to start.  Where do you get stuck?

Comment: In order to get into the general solution would I have to construct a 3X3 matrix and if so what values would I have to put in to the matrix

Comment: Well, from the second equation, you can solve by itself since it is decoupled and find $V(t)$. Then you can substitute that result into the first equation and find $I(t)$ and then repeat for third equation. There are many approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Rewrite the system as:
$$I'(t)=-0.5I(t)+0.06V(t)+0\cdot N(t)$$
$$V'(t)=0\cdot I(t)+cV(t)+0\cdot N(t)$$
$$N'(t)=100I(t)+0\cdot V(t)-cN(t)$$

Then
$\begin{bmatrix} I(t)\\V(t)\\N(t) \end{bmatrix}'=\begin{bmatrix} -.5 & .06 & 0\\ 0 & c & 0 \\ 100 & 0 & -c \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} I(t)\\V(t)\\N(t) \end{bmatrix}$.